# Data View web part causing memory Leak

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt

I first posted my question yesterday at the following URL on stack overflow:

[Creating DataView's on the Pages Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646179/creating-dataviews-on-the-pages-library)

After doing more research, I've concluded that my problem is with my implementation of the data view's accessing various page libraries throughout the site collection.

I found this link which explains exactly what I'm doing; however, there are no comments or answers on how to fix the problem.

[Data view/ Data form web part causes a memory leak](http://blogs.livepoint.com.au/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=30#Comments)

The memory leak is caused by adding the WebUrl  select parameter to point to different page libraries. As I have a different dataviews performing various operations on the same page libraries I'm *guessing* the other connections are being re-opened and not being disposed of correctly. [The reason I've added the WebUrl select parameter is so that I can make the webpart reusable by filtering the Article Type and WebURL across the site making it easy for my client in the future]

Please help if you've encountered this problem and know how to fix it! A simple point in the right direction will also be of service.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I've never seen a memory leak in a DVWP before. Congrads.

So I'm thinking you can treat this leak just like any other leak.  I would run the SPDisposeCheck utility on your DVWP and then use the dispose() method in XSLT.  I've never done either of these things on XSL but I think you can. You may have to port the XSLT to VS2010 to get the utility to attach to the build.